# Random movement in HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics

I am learning html5 for games. I need to move a ball randomly. Now the ball moves from left to right and the player knows where the ball will be. I need that the ball moves randomly.

I attached the code I'm using. There is something miss about random speed and angle, I do not how to write. I am using simplegame.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "simpleGame_1_0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var scene;
  var sprite1;
    function init(){
        scene = new Scene();
        sprite1 = new Sprite(scene, "brand1.png", 90, 90);
        sprite1.setMoveAngle(45);
        sprite1.setSpeed(10);
        scene.start();
      } // end init
   function update(){
        scene.clear();
        //handle events here
        //update all the sprites
        sprite1.update();
        }

    </script>
    </head>
<body onload = "init()">
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the `simplegame.js` code but if the variables are defined on the page you provided it is possible to use a variable that contains a random number.

`Math.random();` returns a random number from 0 up to but not including 1. You can then multiply this number with your maximum value.

It looks like you first initialize the code in the `init()` method (e.g., setup the playing field) and then you can update the sequence with the `update()` function.

Try something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var scene;
 var sprite1;

 function init(){
    scene = new Scene();
    sprite1 = new Sprite(scene, "brand1.png", 90, 90);
    sprite1.setMoveAngle(45);
    sprite1.setSpeed(10);
    scene.start();
  } // end init

  function update(){
    scene.clear();
    //handle events here
    //update all the sprites

    // Here comes the extra code:
    var randomAngle = parseInt(Math.random() * 90); // Random from 0 to 90 degrees
    var randomSpeed = parseInt(Math.random() * 100); // random from 0 to 100 speed
                                                      // Not sure if needed but,
                                                      // the parseInt makes an integer
                                                      // (a value of 0,1,2,3,...n)

    // Now pass the variables into the functions of the sprite (the functions are of  
    // the sprite object and will change its behaviour)
    sprite1.setMoveAngle(randomAngle);
    sprite1.setSpeed(randomSpeed);
    // End of extra code
    sprite1.update();
  }

</script>
```

Does it work?

PS It can be very helpful to install Firebug for FireFox so you can see a window where error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get random numbers in a certain range like this

```
var min = -10;
var max = 10;
// and the formula is:
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Simply replace the static values (45, 10) with such a random variable

```
function init(){
    scene = new Scene();
    sprite1 = new Sprite(scene, "brand1.png", 90, 90);
    sprite1.setMoveAngle(Math.floor(Math.random() * (359 - 0 + 1)) + 0); //Random angle from 0 and 359
    sprite1.setSpeed(Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1)) + 0); //Random speed between 0 and 20
    scene.start();
  } // end init
```

Of curse you can set differnt ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [library documentation](http://aharrisbooks.net/h5g/documentation.html) .

There is a method to solve this: **Use changeImgAngleBy() for animated rotation.**

Also the author has a **fiddle** to [test](http://aharrisbooks.net/h5g/simpleGamePractice.html) anything you need.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I will check the library.